# Measure memory usage when algorithm is running

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have app witch visualize sorting alogrith i want to show user how much memory used each one of them when was runned it should be done on button click my stack is typescript and d3.js . I use Vite.js for building the app.

This is the button click code so far

```
let sortingInProgress = false
    let timeInfo = '0.00 s'
    const sortingPromise = new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        START_BUTTON.addEventListener('click', async () => {
            if (sortingInProgress) {
                console.log('stoped')
                return
            }
            sortingInProgress = true
            START_BUTTON.disabled = true
            SELECT_DATA_SIZE.disabled = true
            SELECT_SORTING_ALGORITHM.disabled = true

            const startTime = performance.now()
            const sort = SelectAlgorithm(data, algorithmType)
            await sort(updateBars)
            const endTime = performance.now()
            const totalTime = ((endTime - startTime) / 1000).toFixed(2) // get alogrithm running time in  seconds
            console.log(totalTime)
            timeInfo = `${totalTime} s`

            resolve()
        })
    })

    sortingPromise.then(() => {
        svg.selectAll('rect').style('fill', 'black')
        sortingInProgress = false
        SELECT_DATA_SIZE.disabled = false
        SELECT_SORTING_ALGORITHM.disabled = false
        SORT_TIME.textContent = timeInfo
    })
```

Comment: measureUserAgentSpecificMemory

Comment: Does this will work for all browsers ?

Comment: Look at MDN....

Comment: ok i checked and this does not support many key browsers maybe there is a more global solution

Comment: There is others that are deprecated, but memory is really not a thing in JS.

Comment: Yeah I know but i want to show the user memory usage of sorting algorithm thats why i need it

Comment: Looks like   Firefox / Safari   just don't think users of a website would find this useful, and expect anyone needing this info would use developer tools.   But even if this info was available it's not going to tell you how much just the sorting algorithm would be taking, as there is GUI memory etc,.  So maybe your best approach is to implement some sort of estimate..

Comment: The deprecated way is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/memory but that is not fully supported. The JS in the browser really does not have access to it.